# Location services control from iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I installed an application from app store that uses gps. I have only put the app on install and it itself was added to the location services with button turned on. Whereas my r&d regarding turning location services on from my iphone app results that i cannot do it directly from my code. Can anybody explain this situation and answer me that whether the app can set location services at install time or is it something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot change the location services settings from your code. 
when you first install/launch the app, it is the OS who ask for the usage of location services from User - not your application when your app just start code to find location.

User is given privilege to enable/disable location services usage for the app - as per apple policy.